# Changing the order of a double integration ? $\int_{-5}^{5}dx\int_{-7}^{\sqrt{25-x^2}}f(x,y)dy$

Tags: calculus, integration

I've been doing an example of changing the order of a double integral and I'm not sure if I did it right. I would really appreciate if someone would check if my solution is right and correct any mistakes.

The example is $\int_{-5}^{5}dx\int_{-7}^{\sqrt{25-x^2}}f(x,y)dy$

The area set by the integral is:

$$-5\leq x \leq 5$$
$$-7 \leq x \leq \sqrt{25-x^2} $$

Here's the graph with selected area. I also divided the area into three parts

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUTsX.png)

1. $$-5 \leq x \leq \sqrt{25-y^2}$$
   $$-5 \leq y \leq 0$$
2. $$-5 \leq x \leq 5$$
   $$-7 \leq x \leq -5$$
3. $$\sqrt{25-y^2} \leq x \leq 5$$
   $$-5 \leq x \leq 0$$

The final answer:
$$\int_{-5}^{0}dy\int_{-5}^{\sqrt{25-y^2}}f(x,y)dx+\int_{-7}^{-5}dy\int_{-5}^{5}f(x,y)dx+\int_{-5}^{0}dy\int_{\sqrt{25-y^2}}^{5}f(x,y)dx$$

Did I do it right?

Answer (score 0):

Almost correct. The integral should be
$$\int_{-5}^{0}dy\int_{-5}^{-\sqrt{25-y^2}}f(x,y)dx+\int_{-7}^{-5}dy\int_{-5}^{5}f(x,y)dx+\int_{-5}^{0}dy\int_{\sqrt{25-y^2}}^{5}f(x,y)dx$$